# Que significan o que es lo que hacen estos tres puntos en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo entendido que se le llama notacion de propagacion, pero no logro entender bien que realiza, o bien, que codigo es el que esta reemplazando, y otra pregunta, cuando usarlas?.

Este es mi ejemplo:

```
<Route path='/inicio' render={(props) => <MainView {...props} isAuthed={this.state.loggedIn} isGod={this.state.isGod} shops={this.state.shops}
              shopDetails={{shopName:this.state.shopName,userName:this.state.userName}} />}
            />
            <Route path='/login' render={(props) => <LoginView {...props} LogIn={this.handleLogin.bind(this)} />}/>
            <Route path='/reset_password/:token' render={(props) => <ResetPassword {...props} /> } />
```

Les agradezco mucho su apoyo! Soy nuevo en React y estoy aprendiendo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Eso es notación de propagación de propiedad, siendo agregado en ES2018 (propuesta aquí, en el borrador de especificación aquí), pero fue respaldado durante mucho tiempo en los proyectos Reaccionar a través de la transpilación (como "atributos de propagación JSX", aunque también podría hacerlo en otros sitios, no solo en los atributos).

`{...this.props}`  se extiende las propiedades en puntales como propiedades discretas (atributos) en Modal elemento que estás creando Por ejemplo, si `this.props` contenido `a: 1 y b: 2`, entonces

```
<Modal {...this.props} title='Modal heading' animation={false}>
```

sería lo mismo que

```
<Modal a={this.props.a} b={this.props.b} title='Modal heading' animation={false}>
```

Pero es dinámico, por lo que cualquier propiedad está en props están incluidos.

La notación de propagación es útil no solo para ese caso de uso, sino también para crear un nuevo objeto con la mayoría (o todas) de las propiedades de un objeto existente, que aparece mucho cuando estás actualizando el estado, ya que no puedes modificar el estado directamente:

```
   this.setState(prevState => {
        return {foo: {...prevState.foo, a: "updated"}};

});
```

Eso reemplaza `this.state.foo` con un nuevo objeto con todas las mismas propiedades que `foo` excepto el a propiedad, que se convierte `"updated"`:

```
const obj = {
  foo: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  }
};
console.log("original", obj.foo);
// Creates a NEW object and assigns it to `obj.foo`
obj.foo = {...obj.foo, a: "updated"};
console.log("updated", obj.foo);
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Un ejemplo más claro sería este:

```
function App1() {
  return <Greeting firstName="Ben" lastName="Hector" />;
}

function App2() {
  const props = {firstName: 'Ben', lastName: 'Hector'};
  return <Greeting {...props} />;
}
```